# how to remove an option from selection drop down box by checking that the value exists in mysql database using javascript

Tags: javascript, java, mysql

How can I remove an option from selection drop down list on the basis that the value already exists in database?

```
<select name="select_time"id="select_time">
  <option value="" disable>SELECT TIMING</option>
  <option value="<%= rs.getString(5)%>"><%= rs.getString(5)%></option>
  <option value="<%= rs.getString(6)%>"><%= rs.getString(6)%></option>
  <option value="<%= rs.getString(7)%>"><%= rs.getString(7)%></option>
  <option value="<%= rs.getString(8)%>"><%= rs.getString(8)%></option>
  <option value="<%= rs.getString(9)%>"><%= rs.getString(9)%></option>
</select>
```

This is the selection box whose values are coming from one table and I have to insert its value into another table. Once the value is inserted in the database, selection box should not show that option to the user.

Comment: in select query select the option list where not in already user_choosen_option table  with where condition for specific  user .   like this select * from option_list_table where option not in (select user_choosed_option from user_choosed_table where user_id=1)

Comment: Thanks for the reply , but I think I didn't made my self clear. All these values of selection box are coming from table1, If user selects any of the value from the selection box  it gets saved in table2.Again any other user fills that form then that option (that was already chosen by first user and is saved in table2) should not appear in the selection box.

Comment: just do the same query without where condition select * from table1 where option not in (select user_choosed_option from table2 )

Answer (score 0):

In `select query` select the option list where not in already `user_choosed_option` table with where condition .like this

```
select * from option_list_table 
where option not in (select user_choosed_option 
                     from user_choosed_table
                     where user_id=1)
```

**Note :** Table names are just for a example . replace it with your right `table name`